# Ember data: computed attributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I like to know if there is way to use computed properties with ember data for example I would like to have totalPrice calculated and saved from based on amount of other properties. Only way I think I can think of doing it using an observer

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing different between an `Ember data model` and an ordinary `Ember Object` you can define computed properties on your models just like you do for your components, controllers, routes, etc. Please check the [official ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/defining-models/). It has the following model example:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr(),
  lastName: DS.attr(),

  fullName: computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  })
});
```

where `fullName` is defined as a computed property depending on `firstName` and `lastName`. Let's create an artificial model that contains `totalPrice` as you wanted:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  originalPrice: DS.attr('number'),
  vat: DS.attr('number'),
  discount: DS.attr('number')

  totalPrice: computed('originalPrice', 'vat', 'discount', function() {
    return this.originalPrice + this.vat - this.discount;
  })
});
```

something similar to above should simply work.

After the comment regarding sending the computed property to backend; sth. similar to below customization for `serializer` should work:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    let json = this._super(...arguments);

    json.totalPrice = snapshot.record.get('totalPrice')

    return json;
  },
});
```

Comment: Yup I understand that part, however I would like that computed property to save with the model the same as the DS.attr ones

Comment: A computed property is not persisted in your API. Are you looking for [default values](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.6/classes/DS/methods/attr?anchor=attr)?

Comment: You can include totalPrice in the JSON sent to the server by customizing your serializer: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers

Comment: @Gaurav I added a custom serializer to the answer; that was sth.  I intended after seeing the comment about sending the `CP` to backend. I did not try the code provided; but I guess what you had in your mind is similar to what I provide. right?